# How to get FontAwesome unicode value from its class name in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, font-awesome

How can I access Fontawesome unicode using its class name
For example- class = far fa-drafting compass

Comment: Does Fontawesome have a nuget package?

Comment: Yes. I have installed Font Awesome 5